# Repetitive process to follow links in a website (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a code in Python to get all the 'a' tags in a URL using Beautiful soup, then I use the link at position 3, then I should follow that link, I will repeat this process about 18 times. I included the code below, which has the process repeated twice. I can't come about a way to repeat the same process 18 times in a loop.Any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import *
htm1= urllib.urlopen('https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html ').read()
soup =BeautifulSoup(htm1)
tags = soup('a')
list1=list()
for tag in tags:
    x = tag.get('href', None)
    list1.append(x)

M= list1[2]

htm2= urllib.urlopen(M).read()
soup =BeautifulSoup(htm2)
tags1 = soup('a')
list2=list()
for tag1 in tags1:
    x2 = tag1.get('href', None)
    list2.append(x2)

y= list2[2]
print y
```

OK, I just wrote this code, it's working but I get the same 4 links in the results. It looks like there is something wrong in the loop (please note: I'm trying the loop 4 times)

```
import re
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
list1=list()
url = 'https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html'

for i in range (4):  # repeat 4 times
    htm2= urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup1=BeautifulSoup(htm2)
    tags1= soup1('a')
    for tag1 in tags1:
        x2 = tag1.get('href', None)
        list1.append(x2)
    y= list1[2]
    if len(x2) < 3:  # no 3rd link
        break  # exit the loop
    else:
        url=y             
    print y
```

Comment: If you don't know how to do `for _ in range(18):` then forget about links and do several [exercises](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex32.html) that use [loops](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-cxMGf/0/1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can't come about a way to repeat the same process 18 times in a loop.

To repeat something 18 times in Python, you could use `for _ in range(18)` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

url = 'http://example.com'
for _ in range(18):  # repeat 18 times
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
    a = soup.find_all('a', href=True)  # all <a href> links
    if len(a) < 3:  # no 3rd link
        break  # exit the loop
    url = urljoin(url, a[2]['href'])  # 3rd link, note: ignore <base href>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursion http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

```
def GetLinks(initialPage):
    htm1= urllib.urlopen(initialPage).read()
    soup =BeautifulSoup(htm1)
    tags = soup('a')
    list1=list()
    for tag in tags:
        x = tag.get('href', None)
        list1.append(x)
        list1.append(GetLinks(x))
    return list1
```

if you want to set a limit on levels you want to go you can pass the level you are at as a param, ex:

```
def GetLinks(initialPage, level):
    level += 1
    htm1= urllib.urlopen(initialPage).read()
    soup =BeautifulSoup(htm1)
    tags = soup('a')
    list1=list()
    for tag in tags:
        x = tag.get('href', None)
        list1.append(x)
        if level < 18:
            list1.append(GetLinks(x))
    return list1
```

Comment: Casey, thank you so much for your help. I have a question, which lines in the def you provided that declare that I need to re-run the process for the URL in the 3rd position?

Comment: The function calls itself, hence recursion. if you look on line 9 you'll see the GetLinks function call GetLinks, this repeats until either you run out of links on the page or have a stack overflow/run out of memory, if you use the 2nd one I posted it calls itself 18 times before quitting (or whatever number you wish to specify.) assuming you call it initially with GetLinks(link, 0)

Comment: recursion is probably an overkill here, a [simple `for`-loop is enough](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33938464/4279).

Comment: Hi J.F. Sebastian, your answer looks great and that is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I'm using Python 2.7 and bs3, so the code you wrote didn't run on my computer. I wrote a similar code with a for loop ( added it above), the code works fine but I get the same 4 links in the result. Obviously, something is wrong in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

URL = raw_input("Enter the URL:") #Put insurance
link_line = int(raw_input("Enter the line of the desired link:")) - 1 #Put insurance
count = int(raw_input("Enter the loop repeat times:")) #Put insurance

while count >= 0:
    html = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = soup('a')
    print URL
    URL = tags[link_line].get("href", None)
    count = count - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = raw_input('http://example')
for i in range(18):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    tags = soup('a')
    s = []

    for tag in tags:
        x = tag.get('href', None)
        s.append(x)
    print s[3]
    url = s[3]
print "ansver:", s[3]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. For the future please don't provide code-only answers. Always add some explanation to your solution. This makes it easier for people to follow your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url='http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Eesa.html'
counts=raw_input('Enter number of pages to jump: ')
counts=int(counts)
pos=raw_input('Enter position: ')
pos=int(pos)
y1= list()
y2=list()
count=0
while True:
   data=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
   soup= BeautifulSoup(data)
   tags=soup('a')
   for tag in tags:
       value=tag.get('href',None)
       value=str(value)
       y1.append(value)
   t=y1[pos-1]
   y2.append(t)
   y1=[]
   count=count+1 
   if count==counts:break
   else:
    url=t
    continue
print y2
```

Comment: Could you please provide a short description of what the code does?

Comment: after doing** BeautifulSoap(data)** put all the anchor<a> tags  in a list.Run the loop through this list, extract the **href** value and you will get a list (y1) with all **href** values of a single page then select the value of required position and add it to another list y2 and then clear the list y1 using **y1[]** so that at the same desired position in the next cycle you have different value of href in list y1.You are basically collecting  links of the desired position of all the pages into list y2  and then at the end change the url with the next link you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = input('Enter - ')

def functiontofollowlink(url):

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    count=0
    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        #print(tag.get('href', None))
        count = count+1
        if count==18:
           url=tag.get('href', None)
return url
numberoftimes = int(input('Enter number of times to repeat:'))
#for fisrt you need to give the link then for numberoftimes decrease number by 1
#since we know previously which position to check so directly used in the function count = 18 else you can give number externally
#positionoflink = input('Enter position of the link:')

while numberoftimes>=0:
    numberoftimes=numberoftimes-1
    url=functiontofollowlink(url)

print(url)
```

*This gives you exact query output that you wanted*

Answer (score 1):

I would use for loop inside for loop to repeat, and use count to break to make it stop at the link you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
import re

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
url = "your first link here"
#to repeat 18 times#
for i in range(18):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    count = 0
    for tag in tags:
        count = count +1
        #make it stop at position 3#
        if count>3:
            break
        url = tag.get('href', None)
print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
url = input('Enter :')
for i in range(7): #to repeat 7 times
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    count = 0
    for tag in tags:
        count = count +1
        if count>18: #to stop after printing 18th name
            break
        url = tag.get('href', None)
        if count == 18: #to print 18th name
            print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that using a while loop makes the code more clean, with the option that you can change the input of that code.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import ssl
    
    # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    
    url = input('Enter url: ')
    
    count = input('Enter count: ')
    count = int(count)
    
    pos = input('Enter position:')
    pos = int(pos)
    
    while count > 0:
        # Re-opens the link
        html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        
        #Extract 'href=' values
        lst= list()
        tags = soup("a")
        for tag in tags:
            href = tag.get("href", None)
            lst.append(href)
        #prints only the url 'http:/...'
        url = lst[pos]
        #prints out the url on that position
        print('Retrieving:', url)
        
        #makes sure the loop isn't infinite
        count = count - 1
```