# Webscraping using BeautifulSoup- unable to follow the link

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This portion is with regard to the pyinformatics course in coursera by dr. chuck. since it was in py2.0 , i do not have much assistance while using py 3.0 . I am trying to scrape a website which has x links. after collecting the links , i browse through and zero-in on particular link( say a link at position 3 of list of x links). I would like to pursue the link and I am supposed to repeat it for n counts.
The problem is i could get the output for only the first time. Following it for the successive times i get the same result( i.e.,I am unable to feed in the output for successive parsing . Please see the code and help me where i am going wrong. This is my first question. indentation with the code seems to work fine

> 

```
import urllib.request 
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
> import json
> import ssl
> 

> scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1) 
  url = input('Enter -')
  count = int(input('Count'))
  pos = int(input('position')) 
  y = 0 
  n = pos- 1 
  html =urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=scontext).read() 
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 
  tags = soup.find_all('a')
  x =[tag.get('href') for tag in tags]
  print(x[n]) 
  new_url = str(x[n])

> 
> 
> while y<count:
>     html =urllib.request.urlopen(new_url, context=scontext).read()
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
>     tags = soup.find_all('a')
>     x = [tag.get('href') for tag in tags]
>     url = str(x[n])
>     print(new_url)
>     y = y+1
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057275/following-certain-links-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repetitive process to follow links in a website (BeautifulSoup)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930724/repetitive-process-to-follow-links-in-a-website-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

```
while y<count:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(new_url, context=scontext).read()
...
```

In your while loop your request use 'new_url', but this never changes in the loop. You do set the variable called 'url' in the while loop, but that is never used.

Change:

```
url = str(x[n])
```

To:

```
new_url = str(x[n])
```

in the while loop. Hopefully that helps with the problem :)